# SharePoint Background

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I upload a new image to the site, and even thou I change the quality and size of the picture, it still displayed stretch and fuzzy. How do I avoid the background to look like that?

Comment: where u are displaying image? in a web part or embedding in page or etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the site background from Site settings , Look and feel , change the look , drag your image here

[image]

Comment: All backgrounds that I add, look fuzzy. Even thou I change the size. How can I avoid that from happening? Do you know any websites I can obtain images suitable for sharepoint?